# Print if remainder of division with certain number is zero - Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, progress-bar

I am running a big loop  and I want to see the progress. I want the code to print the index of the iteration  when the remainder of that number with 1e4 is zero. What I ve tried so far looks like this:

```
print(i if (i%1e4==0))
```

But it doesn seem to work. I cant use any functions such as qdtm because I am also using numba and it does not accept it. Any help?

Comment: The conditional operator requires an `else` clause.

Comment: I want to see a progress bar while running a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional operator requires an `else` value. If you don't want to print anything when the condition is false, you need to use an ordinary `if` statement, not a conditional expression.

```
if i % 1e4 == 0:
    print(i)
```

If it really has to be a single statement, you could make use the the `end` argument to `print()` to print nothing, and then include the newline in the output you print.

```
print(str(i) + '\n' if i % 1e4 == 0 else '', end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(int(1e5)):
    if (i%1e4==0):
        print(i)
```

Outputs:

```
0
10000
20000
30000
40000
50000
60000
70000
80000
90000
```